# Function to check user birth date is 18 years or upper not always work correctly

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner webdeveloper.
I use in my project Laravel 5.8.
I have this this code:

```
if ($this->calcutateAge($request->input('date')) < 18) {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['You are a minor. Registration is allowed for adult users']);
        }

function calcutateAge($dob)
    {

        $dob = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob));

        $dobObject = new DateTime($dob);
        $nowObject = new DateTime();

        $diff = $dobObject->diff($nowObject);

        return $diff->y;

    }
```

It's work fine. But I have problem with date ex 2045-12-12.
This function is not working. With year: 2015-12-12 - it's okey.

How can I repair it?

Comment: There can't be anyone born on "2045-12-12" yet?

Comment: You need to check if `$dob` is before `$nowObject`.

Comment: Yes, you want to protect yourself from entering wrong dates, future birthdays, etc.

Comment: I would suggest using a comparison (`<`/`>`) instead of diff, along with calculating today's date 18 years ago.

Comment: I have second function to secure correct date format: if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/", $request->input('date'))) {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Wpisany format daty jest niepoprawny']);
        }.

Comment: I have a problem with birthdays written "into the future"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write your function to return `true` or `false` depending on if the user is 18 or not.

```
function is_18($dob)
{
    $dobObject = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob)));
    $nowObject = new DateTime();
    
    return $dobObject < $nowObject ? ($dobObject->diff($nowObject)->y > 18) : false;
}
```

Then your `IF` block is simplified to this:

```
if (!$this->is_18($request->input('date')) {
     return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['You are a minor. Registration is allowed for adult users']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you should use Carbon.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

function calcutateAge($dob){
      return \Carbon::parse($dob)->age;
}
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion because it's already included in Laravel.

Comment: Except it didn't work with a birthdate of 2045-12-12. I tried it and got 25. :/

Comment: You can still make a double check `\Carbon::parse($dob) > today() ? 0 : $age`

Answer (score 1):

I would find out when a person born 18 years ago was born, then compare to that:

```
function isAdult($dob) {
    $adult = new DateTime('18 years ago'); // 'date' => '2002-09-01 12:05:52.000000'
    $dob = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob));

    $dobObject = new DateTime($dob);

    return $adult >= $dobObject; // 2002-09-01 is after the passed date of birth

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add 18 year and compare the date like this:

```
$dobObject = new DateTime($dob.' +18 years');
$nowObject = new DateTime();
if ($dobObject > $nowObject)
    print 'great you are granted'
else
    print 'sorry you are minor'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run `var_dump($diff);` you will see:

```
["invert"]=> int(1)
```

Which means is a negative difference.

So, you can do `return $diff->invert? -$diff->y : $diff->y;`

Of course this is a solution based on your code. You can always check if the date is someday into the future, and return false or throw some exception in this case.